# Javascript issue - intermittently cannot find element using getElementById

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I am having a problem with some javascript that I wrote that is only working intermittently.  I dont know a huge amount about how things work in the DOM but I suspect that the JS that I have written is trying to access an element in the DOM before it exists.  I wrote the JS to add it to a formassembly form.  I do not have access to the actual code in the form to make changes there, I can only make JS changes.

Here is the link to the form http://www.tfaforms.com/186347

and this is the javascript that I am using on document load

```
 window.onload=function() {

document.getElementById("submit-").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("wfPageNextId1").value="Calculate";
document.getElementById('wfPageNextId1').setAttribute('onclick', 'Calculate2011()')

}
```

I am getting errors saying that wfPageNextId1 is null and setAttribute cannot be called.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some of the DOM is getting created dynamically by other scripts. You can delay until the elements exist via something along these lines:

```
function initializeForm() {
   var submit = document.getElementById("submit-"),
       nextPage = document.getElementById("wfPageNextId1");
   if (submit && nextPage) {
      submit.style.visibility = "hidden";
      nextPage.value = "Calculate";
      nextPage.setAttribute('onclick', 'Calculate2011()');
   } else {
      // try again in 1 second
      setTimeout(initializeForm, 1000);
   }
}

window.onload = function() {
   initializeForm();
};
```

You should also make sure you are not nuking any `window.onload` defined in the other scripts:

```
if (window.onload) {
   var currentOnload = window.onload;
   window.onload = function() { currentOnload(); initializeForm(); };
} else {
   window.onload = function() { initializeForm(); };
}
```

Comment: this makes logical sense to me.  It is changing the label on the calculate button and hiding the submit button but it is not actually doing the calculations, not in IE anyway, but it is in crome.  Any other suggestions.  I'm not sure what you mean about other window.onloads?

Comment: Also appears to be working in firefox but not IE8.  There are no javascript errors on the page so not sure what the issue is and why it is not going into the Calculate2011 function.  I put an alert into the function and it is not displayed in IE but it is in FF and Crome

Comment: I added an example of a "safe" `onload` definition. Technically you should probably test the type of the current `onload`.

Comment: Other window.onloads: someone else might have assigned a function to window.onload. By assigning it yourself you will remove the previous function and it won't load.

Comment: window on load code didn't make any difference in IE.  Still not getting to the calculate method.  Another option may be to do something to the first input on the second page called "tfa_TotalAnnualIncom".  This field is calculated by form assemble after the next page button is clicked.  Any suggestions for a way to put some sort of an onchange event on this field to then call the calculate 2011 function?

Comment: I think IE is evaluating and executing the expression "Calculate2011()" when it creates the attribute. It throws an error for me when the page loads. Try assigning it as `nextPage.onclick = Calculate2011;` (no quotes).

Comment: I replaced nextPage.setAttribute('onclick', 'Calculate2011()'); with nextPage.onclick = function(){Calculate2011();} and now it seems to be working in IE.  Thanks for all the suggestions and quick replies.  Gosh I hate IE!!!

Answer (score 1):

Checked the page HTML and infact there is no HTML element with the id wfPageNextId1.
What is the element on the page that you are trying to access?

Comment: I'm trying to access the Next Page button (I am changing the text on the button to "calculate") and then I need to call the Calculate2011 function on the click of that button

Comment: I think you are adding the element dynamically and document.getElementById("wfPageNextId1") statement is being called even before the element is created and added to dom.